# Selenium2Library trouble with selectors

Tags: python, selenium, selector, selenium2library

I'm doing some testing with Selenium2Library and I'm having some trouble with element selector.
I have tried many. many different ways and none seem to work. What I want to do is to test the functionality of logging in/registering but I just can't find the right way.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  This is some basic info
Library  Selenium2Library
*** Variables ***

*** Keywords ***

*** Test Cases ***
Check log in and register

    open browser  http://www.999.md
    set browser implicit wait  5
    click element  css=div.user-login-btn
```

This is the error I always get:

> ValueError: Element locator 'css=div.user-login-btn' did not match any elements.

Comment: @Pri Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CSS` selector intend to match `<div class="user-login-btn">`, but target element is actually `<div id="user-login-btn">`, so what you need is

```
css=div#user-login-btn
```

Note that `"."` in `CSS` selector stands for [*class*](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) attribute selector while `"#"` - for [*id*](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp) attribute selector

Comment: @Andresson I have tried that and it also does not work. I get the same error.

Comment: This is because button located inside an `iframe` with `id="topbar-panel"`. You need to switch to that `iframe` to be able to handle button

Comment: @Andresson I didn't know that, I'm still very new to this. How can I do that? After some googling a only managed to find this in web driver not in selenium2library.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with `selenium2library` syntax at all...